# SQL Azure database design issue

Tags: sql, .net, azure

I am building a database to store Categories, and every Category has multiple sub-categories.

I am trying to find the best way to design this but Cant really think of anything except creating one table for each category, this feels a bit messy seeing how there will be at least 50 Categories. Is there a way I can create a "Category"-table and somehow have a column called "SubCategories" that lists multiple strings? If so, how would I split these subcategories so I can retrieve them without a problem from my application?

Comment: I was thinking, what if I made a table for categories and gave them all a uniqe ID, then I made a table for sub-categories and gave them the corresponding ID. Would I be able to retrieve the right subcategories for each category from my application this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is the solution most people would go with.

Create a table `Categories`, and a second table `SubCategories`.

`Categories` would have a unique primary key `CategoryID` (think `Identity`).

`SubCategories` would have a primary key `SubCategoryID` and a **Foreign Key** `CategoryID`

> Now lets say you have a category in your code and you want to get all of its SubCategories:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID BIGINT = 23
SELECT s.SubCategoryID, s.CategoryID, s.Name 
FROM SubCategories s 
WHERE s.CategoryID = @CategoryID
```

Of course if you are using a database access technology like *Entity Framework* then you most likely won't be writing this kind of SQL as *EF* would take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks, will go with this :)